# TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform giving type error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am new to scikit-learn. I need to calculate the tf-idf vectors for a large corpus. But before beginning on that, I tried coding for a few small documents consisting of not more than 5-6 words each. The specific code that I wrote is as given below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text 
import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(docList)
```

It is running fine on my laptop but is generating the following error when I run it on a server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp1.py", line 49, in <module>
    tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(docList)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1285, in fit_transform
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 825, in fit_transform
max_features)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 697, in _limit_features
    dfs = _document_frequency(X)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 491, in _document_frequency
    return bincount(X.indices, minlength=X.shape[1])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 345, in bincount
    return np.bincount(x, weights, minlength)
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Is this a problem with the version of sklearn installed? I have 0.17.1 installed in my laptop and the server has sklearn 0.16.1 installed. Since my corpus is very large, I have to run it on the server, else I will naturally face memory issues.

Any insight into this problem will be appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: Which version of numpy is installed on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to a faulty installation of numpy, reported [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4691%20here).

You may run the test and check that (nose required):

```
pip install nose
nosetests -v numpy
nosetests -v sklearn
```

If that's the case, you'll need to remove numpy (and maybe also scikit-learn) and reinstall them using the recommended instructions: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

Using conda could be a good choice too: https://www.continuum.io/downloads